How can I design a Turing machine that recognizes the language { $aⁿbᵐ: m ≥ 2n }?
There are many examples of how to do anbm: m>=0 but not this.
Right now I get that for every a there must be at least two b's marked off on the tape. What is stumping me even more is that m is greater than or equal to 2. So abbb should be accepted. If I replace every a with an X and every bb with a Y, there will still be one leftover b.
I am confused on how the Turing machine handles this. The problem I am running into is that strings like $bab should not be accepted and if I write that any leftover b's lead to an accept state, I am worried strings that like that will falsely be accepted.


there will still be one leftover b

This should not be a problem. Just check that the left over only consists of b (zero or more) and are to the right of any of the already marked X and Y. If that is the case: accept.
The transition table could be like this (_ represents a blank):



state
read
write
move head
next state




start
$

right
readA


readA
a
X
right
findB


readA
Y or _

right
verify


findB
a or Y

right
findB


findB
b
Y
right
findB2


findB2
b
Y
left
repeat


repeat
Y or a

left
repeat


repeat
X

right
readA


verify
Y or b

right
verify


verify
_

left
accept



If the process ends in the accept state, the input belongs to the language. If the process ends in another state, the input does not belong to the language.
Below is an implementation that you can run here on the spot. Run the snippet and then load the input you want to have on the tape and click the Play button:


createTuring({
    transitions: [
        { state: "start",  read: "$",             move: "R", nextState: "readA"  },
        { state: "readA",  read: "a", write: "X", move: "R", nextState: "findB"  },
        { state: "readA",  read: "Y_",            move: "R", nextState: "verify" },
        { state: "findB",  read: "aY",            move: "R", nextState: "findB"  },
        { state: "findB",  read: "b", write: "Y", move: "R", nextState: "findB2" },
        { state: "findB2", read: "b", write: "Y", move: "L", nextState: "repeat" },
        { state: "repeat", read: "Ya",            move: "L", nextState: "repeat" },
        { state: "repeat", read: "X",             move: "R", nextState: "readA"  },
        { state: "verify", read: "Yb",            move: "R", nextState: "verify" },
        { state: "verify", read: "_",             move: "L", nextState: "accept" },
    ],
    initState: "start",
    tape: "$aaabbbbbbbb",
});
<script src="https://trincot.github.io/turing.js"></script>



